# OneDrive Expects Boundary for Content-Type: application/json

Tags: onedrive

This is a recent development. We run integration tests against this API on every commit.

```
POST https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive

Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "My example folder"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "request_header_invalid",
        "message": "The header 'Content-Type' is missing the required parameter: 'boundary'."
    }
}
```

Requiring a boundary for an application/json content-type is just wrong. But lets try it:

```
POST https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive

Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json; boundary=idontactuallybelonghere

{
    "name": "My example folder"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "request_header_invalid",
        "message": "The header 'Content-Type' is missing the required parameter: 'boundary'."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create a folder? That error sounds like it thinks you're trying to upload a file using a multipart/form-data POST.

Are you using the exact URL as in your example? I tried that exact request against my account and it worked. I was able to reproduce your error, though, by using a URL that ends in '/files' like I would for a file upload.